# Find min and max index where value is not Zero

Tags: r

I have a vector called test that contains 8 elements.

I want to return a vector called points that contains the MAX and MIN of the test vector where test cannot be zero.  i.e. I do not want 0 to be the minimum or the maximum

Here is my code

```
test<- c(1,8,2,3,4,5,0,7)
test

points <- c((1:length(test))[  (test ==  min(test, na.rm = TRUE) | test == max(test,     na.rm = TRUE)  ) && test != 0    ])
points
```

Right now points returns

```
integer(0)
```

I want points to return

```
1 2
```

because 1 is the index of the minimum and 2 is the index of the maximum

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use `range` and `match`, it's faster than a custom function:

```
vals = range(test[test != 0])
match(vals, test)
```

Answer (score 2):

This function might do what you want...

```
minmax <- function(v){
  v.na <- v
  v.na[v==0] <- NA
  return(c( which.min(v.na), which.max(v.na) ))
}
minmax(test)
```

All the best

Comment: +1 - I feel `which.min` and `which.max` will be more robust than `match` if the input is numeric. It's also faster despite what was claimed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `match` function after removing the zero values:

```
test<- c(1,8,2,3,4,5,0,7)
test2 <- test[test!=0]
match(c(min(test2 ),max(test2)),test)
```